# Horizontal scale of nodejs TCP Server

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to horizontally scale my nodejs TCP Server.

Example server:

```
var socketServer = net.createServer(function (socket) {

        // Identify this client
        socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort

        // Put this new client in the list
        clients.push(socket);
        sockets[socket.name] = socket;


        // Handle incoming messages from clients.
        socket.on('data', function (data) {

                // Write to a specific user
                var socketName = "xx.xx.xx.xx:56512";
                sockets[socketName].write("Hello!");

            }

        }).listen(8080);
```

The following example stores each new connection in an array so that we can write a message to  a specific user down the road.

I would like to scale this with `haproxy` as the loadbalancer. But how can i get all of my servers to share the same array of connected clients?

Stickysessions is not a solution that would work for me, since two people talking (two clients) could be on different servers, so all servers somehow have to share the same array of connected clients.

Any ideas how this can be done?

An idea i had:

- Is it maybe possible to store each connection in MySQL?

**Edit**
Maybe the only way of actually doing this is by using `Redis`? 
Any ideas if that would be a suitable option? The load is going to be extremely heavy

Answer (score 1):

1.Use Redis to share your session with your servers.

2.Write a Login-Server,all users should login in Login-Server.
firstly.Login-server will generate  a session,and share session on Redis-server and return transaction server ip and port,

Secondly,Client receive ip and port, disconnect Login-server, and connect to the transaction server,

Lastly,You can provide several TCP servers to handle transaction,Login-server will balance load through ip and port. of course, you can use haproxy to do that.but i don't know how to configure it.